# Converting files found from os.listdir() to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python code to read files from a certain directory where there are multiple files being uploaded daily and I have to read the files that start with a certain keyword.The problem is that print statement shows the correct filename but when I convert them into pandas data frame FileNotFoundError is thrown.I am using the code below:

```
    for fn in os.listdir('Data\Input_Data'):
        if fn.startswith (var2):
           print ('using file',fn)
           data4 = pd.read_csv(fn)
           print(data4)
```

Comment: What is your working directory?```os.listdir ``` return only the file names. If your working directory is different from ```'Data\Input_Data'``` you will not be able to find the files. In that case you need to use ```pd.read_csv(os.path.join('Data\Input_Data', fn))```

Answer (score 0):

That's beacuse you are not specifying the path when calling `pd.read_csv`.

```
for fn in os.listdir('Data\Input_Data'):
    if fn.startswith (var2):
       print ('using file',fn)
       data4 = pd.read_csv('Data\Input_Data'+fn)
       print(data4)
```